# num rows is 3 but the while loop execute only once

Tags: while-loop, prepared-statement

num of rows is true, but while loop executes only once, i don't know what's wrong!
$contt is the number of rows.

```
 if ($stmt = $con->prepare("select COUNT(*) AS countt bla bla"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("...");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($countt);
while($stmt->fetch())
{
    echo "============".$countt."============"; //
}
$stmt->close();
}
the result is:

============ 3 ============

i expect:

============ 3 ============
============ 3 ============
============ 3 ============
```

Comment: shiva to irani hasti engar, agha in kar nmide

Comment: :D my english is terrible , sorry ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've got a `group by` clause buried inside your `bla bla` part of the query, a `count(*)` query can only EVER return a single row...

Since you say `num_rows` is TRUE, that just means `num_rows == 1` - **ONE** row.

Comment: what u meen? group by? i'm new to php and mysql, my query is something like this:
select count * AS count, name phone, from join of three tables bla bla

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_by_%28SQL%29#Queries

Answer (score 0):

Select count will only return one row.
try it manually and you will confirm that fact

Comment: thank u soooo much, my reputation is not enough to like your comment but it works know, i didn't know!